# All .Net Core console-outputs are written to the system log?

Tags: .net-core

I have made a Linux .Net Core console app.
All console-outputs from this app are logged into the system log (systemd journal).

I didn't setup any logging at all in the code.

Comment: Voting to reopen. After the edit, the question is about .NET Core development on Linux, and may have use for future visitors.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Appears that OP is a user and not the developer, though, and "how do I adjust the config file for a program someone else wrote?" is not a development question.

Comment: I've found a lot of info about how to implement your own logging using using Microsoft.Extenstions..., ConfigurationBuilder etc) But there seems to be a native/standard logging configuration in .Net Core console apps. Any hints on how to configure this easily? I just want to disable it

Comment: Just made a new "Hello World" app and it doesn't create any logs...hmmm, so it's not a general problem as a thought. I'll continue searching for the course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a new project and copied everything to the new project.
Nothing is logged now to the system log....strange!

I might have started the original project in VS 2015.
Now using VS 2017 community version.
Maybe the previous VS had a bug.

There must be a setting somewhere in some file but I gave up finding it.

At least my log will not be filled up with console "screen-dumps" now :-P

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to change the logging location using the inbuilt logging functionality in .Net Core. However using the Serilog File Extensions package you can log to a file in a location of your choosing or alternatively to external apps.

If you want to turn logging off set the logging level in your appSettings to None. This is an example:

```
    Dev:
  "Logging": {
"IncludeScopes": false,
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug",
  "System": "Information",
  "Microsoft": "Information"
}
}
Non Dev is a single liner:
"Logging": "Error",
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how set this in the "appSettings"?
My app is called "config" and I have a few auto generated .json file in the app folder (config.deps.json, config.runtimeconfig.dev.json, config.runtimeconfig.json). Are one of those the appSettings file?
If so how would the section look like (none of them include any log related sections)?

Comment: Hmm can't format code in responses. Let me edit the original comment.